# node js get cookie from 302 redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, request, http-headers

I want to simulate a login with node js. The request is a post request and returns 302.

When i want to simulate it with a request in node i get error:

```
Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 302
```

But when i look at google chrome the response is empty but there is a Cookie Response. How can i get this cookie with a node request?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code for getting cookies:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: AppConstants.URLs.PROXY,
    data: message,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
        console.log("Cookie: " + xhr.getResponseHeader("Set-Cookie"));
    }
});
```

You can set cookies from server side at node.js using  **[Cookies-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies-js)**

> How can i get this cookie with a node request?

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var window = jsdom.jsdom().parentWindow;
var Cookies = require('cookies-js')(window);

// First set a cookie
Cookies.set('key', 'value');

// Get the cookie value
Cookies.get('key'); // "value"

// Using the alias
Cookies('key'); // "value"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i am using a javascript file without browser. Is it possible to use jQuery without browser? Because i have no DOM

Comment: I have updated the answer, you can get the DOM using **jsdom**.

Comment: He said he has no DOM.

Comment: As far as I know, cookies are browser entities and Not sure if we could run jquery without the browser.